# ArcGIS Split Raster tool results in black rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, tiles

I have a rather large raster that I am trying to split into small tiles in PNG format to upload to Autodesk Infrastructure.

I came across the [Split Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000009v000000) tool and thought it would do exactly what I wanted, so I tried using it.

The result was a series of raster in the correct place, but they were all completely black.

When I tried to add them in ArcMap they looked fine, but everywhere else they were black.

I thought maybe the raster was too large, so I tried it on a small segment and the exact same thing happened.

Anyone know what the problem is and/or how to fix this?

It would be much easier and faster than trying to figure out a way to do this programatically using clip and a series of square polygons.

Comment: Same outcome here with PNG files, works fine however on any other format, e.g. jpeg

Comment: Have you tried to recalculate the statistics?

Comment: I tried exporting to different formats as well. Tifs came out black as well, jpgs resulted in "invalid raster".

Comment: Update: I think the NoData values on the raster are causing the problem. I clipped out a section without any NoData values and the Split seems to work the way I want it to. Any ideas how I could use it on the whole raster with the NoData values in order to get it to work? I need those NoData values so that the tiles are transparent where there isn't any data.